# Recommendation - How to see order of all functions invoked in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I currently inherited a very complicated code base (back end code / node / javascript).  This code is basically the code that is executed for about at least 50 api endpoints (all in one repo / workspace).  This means the code has a lot of files and functions.  It is also organized in such a way that sometimes the functions will call functions in the same file (as well as other files).  Most of the time for the endpoint to complete - the code hits about 40+ functions... It is a complete nightmare for me to see the journey of what functions are called / in what order when an api endpoint is engaged.

My ask is this: what is a good way in vscode to keep track of all the functions that are invoked for a certain api endpoint path?

Acceptable answers: honestly - anything that can tell you / remember the order of what functions are invoked... and obviously - I am willing to go through the "journey" once and mark whatever functions the endpoints hit... but it's a nightmare remembering all 40+ functions it goes through....

So I even just tried opening up each function in a separate tab and place the tab sequentially from left to right (in order)... however this poses a problem when the function is referencing a function within the same file... (you cannot open a duplicate tab of the same file)

I also looked into the bookmarks extension in vscode... this is what I may end up doing - where I label bookmarks with numbers... but wondering if there is a better solution...

I also looked into the native "Outline" feature in vscode - that's great, but shows me all functions / no order.

I also installed the extension "codemap" in vscode - couldn't figure out how it worked to see if it was actually useful

Comment: I don't know the Visual Studio Code feature set. But the profiler in Visual Studio will, as a side-effect of reporting function timings, give you a tree display of all the calls, showing hierarchically which methods calls which other methods (as well as, of course, how much time is spend in each method).

Comment: There is a a command: `editor.showCallHierarchy` but it needs to be implemented for the language you are using.  `Shift+Alt+H`

Comment: I sincerely apologize, I only have visual-studio-code and not visual studio.